# How to clear cached latitude & longitude details in Windows 8 Store app

Tags: windows-8

When I try to access some Windows 8 Store geolocation apps, I see that the latitude & longitude details are cached i.e. they show coordinates of my earlier location and not the city that I'm currently in.

How can these geolocation details be cleared - either manually or programmatically?